# Everything else equal, would a shorter driver hold an advantage over a taller driver in the same specification race car?

Tags: acceleration

I know it is a closed system, but it seems like being short would be advantageous for turning/acceleration.

Answer (score 2):

*Height* is unlikely to be a relevant factor in acceleration unless the driver was so tall that their head stuck up into the airflow.

*Weight* **is** a factor in as the increase in total mass of driver and car would reduce acceleration (although unless the driver was very heavy/light or they were in a very light vehicle, the difference my not be significant). In principle the vehicle would also decelerate more slowly with a heavier driver, which may be disadvantageous in some situations.

Similarly, the height of the driver is unlikely to be a factor in handling unless they were so tall that they raised the centre of gravity of the driver/vehicle combination.

Without knowing anything about the vehicle setup it is impossible to know if the weight of a driver would have any significant effect on turning - in some cases extra weight, appropriately distributed, may help with handling.

Answer (score 2):

In practice, the differences are so slight that nearly every other aspect of car design will be vastly more important.  However, if we invented a perfect mirror world, we could explore the difference.

As Penguino mentioned, the biggest issue would be weight.  Simply put, the car would accelerate slower.  Now we're not talking about Bowser in Mario Karto slow.  It'd just be a little.  But more mass means less acceleration for the same force.

What if we just stretched the person like taffy?  Then they could have the same mass.  Then the difference is going to be smaller still.  The center of mass of the driver would be higher for the taller person.  That would affect cornering.  It would be harder to take a tight corner if you were taller because your car wants to tip over more.  Your angular inertia is higher, so you'd also find the car shifts on its suspension to corner slower.

But practically speaking, these differences are so small that we would have to consider other effects as well.  For example, the two drivers see the track from different angles.  This could have a larger effect on how the drivers drive than the differences in their centers of mass.